# Dynamic CFTab onClose event

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I simply can't find any real documentation on [ColdFusion Layout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a01.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71d8) Tabs. For the most part I've got them working, but I'd like to tie some logic to a close event. I was wondering if anyone had a working example they could show me? The catch is that I will need to trigger these events in JavaScript. ***But if you have a working version in plain ColdFusion, I'd still love to see it!***

```
var tab = ColdFusion.Layout.getTabLayout("innerTabLayout").activeTab._cf_body;

$('#' + tab).on('close', blah); // doesn't work

tab.on('close', blah) // doesn't work

ColdFusion.Layout.getTabLayout("innerTabLayout").activeTab._cf_body.onTabClose( function(), blah ); //doesn't work
```

I have also tried setting the event on tab creation:

```
var tab = ColdFusion.Layout.createTab();

tab.onTabClose()

tab.on('close');
```

However, none of these work either. I've tried looking at EXT.JS which is what CFtabs were created from, but I don't seem to have any luck there either.

The Coldfusion.Layout object has a function for tab closing, so there must be a way to trigger it! (I would think, haha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending some ***too much*** messing around with the tab, I've got a solution.

```
ColdFusion.Layout.getTabLayout('innerTabLayout').activeTab.on('close', function(e) {

   console.log(this) //this will return the tab object

   console.log(e)//this also returns the tab object

});
```

This will trigger the event when the active tab within a parent is closed. I'm interested to see if there's another, better solution.